# Gnome menu crashes or misbehaves while creating or opening folders in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS(fresh install)

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel

I just updated to ubuntu 20.04 lts using bootable usb, the installations and set up everthing went fine but when i tried opening/creating folders it suddenly clears out all apps from the menu screen and creates more app entries(dots on the right side of menu screen) and the whole system halts i.e i cant launch any other app or even shutdwon my system only move the cursor on the screen .

Please help! 
My rig: Dell XPS l412z
i5-2340m
8gb ram
HD graphics 3000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with the Ubuntu dock extension. Look at this:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1242658/1086027

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1872268