# folder and app page dot indicator bug on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: indicator, 20.04

this is happened when i open the folder, and sometime i got freeze on my system, and the page app indicator turn into many as this video : [folder and app page dot indicator bug on ubuntu 20.04](https://youtube.com/watch?v=mUdlMDsKS3M)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug has been reported here [Gnome Shell completely freezes in Ubuntu 20.04 when clicking outside of app icon folders](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1872268). The cause of the problem is the Ubuntu Dock extension. I solved the problem by changing an extension setting.

How to solve:

1. Install dconf

   ```
   sudo apt install dconf-editor
   ```
2. Go to `/org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/extend-height`
3. Deselect the "Use default value". And set "Custom value" to "False".

There's a video here showing how I did it [bug: application's icon folders](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3N9lnGMj-8).

Comment: Thankyou, it solved, but the ubuntu dock it's not full, but no problem, thankyou

Answer (score 0):

- Install `dconf̀` Editor (`sudo apt install dconf-editor` )
- Go to `/org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock`
- Check for `custom-theme-running-dots-color`
- Select and enter the Hex color code you want or you can copy and paste the default one that is shown there.

This should fix the problem if you installed any custom themes.

Comment: Thankyou, but not that the problem :)